How to import CSV file into MATLAB using only low I/O commands?
I'm trying to import data from this csv file into MATLAB which contains 3 columns and 524 rows.
csv file
I'm only permitted to use low I/O commands such as fopen, fscan, fprintf... so I've started with the following commands:
Filename ='Text.csv';
FileID=fopen(Filename, 'r');
Header = fgetl(Filename);
I clicked run to check if it's getting imported correctly however my variable FileID keeps coming out as 1 then 2, then 3, it just keeps increasing by 1 each time I click run. What I need is a table with all the values and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong unless this code is incomplete.

Header = fgetl(FileID); not Header = fgetl(Filename);. You only need to open it once, then use fgetl for each line.

I appreciate the help! Sorry, I'm not very good at Matlab but how do I use fgetl for each line? Is it just this?
fgetl(FileID);
fgetl(FileID);

see my answer below.

Use fgetl(FileID); not fgetl(Filename);.
"how do I use fgetl for each line? Is it just this? fgetl(FileID); fgetl(FileID);" Generally you'll want to do something with each line, rather than just read and discard.
Here is a sample file:
y Fred
n Karen
y Janice
y John

Here is some code to read and each line and display each line that has a y as the first character:
FileID = fopen(Filename, 'r');
while ~feof(FileID)
    thisline =  fgetl(FileID);
    if thisline(1) == 'y'
        disp(thisline)
    end
end
fclose(FileID)

Here is the output:
y Fred
y Janice
y John

